# Consulta Linq para roles

Tags: c#, linq

[image: Anexo la consulta que tengo]

Tengo esta consulta con Linq que me esta mostrando todos los usuarios con todos los roles. Necesito mostrar los usuarios que tengan asignado solo un rol, hago una consulta en la cual comparo que el rol sea igual a "Admin", para solo mostrar las personas con ese rol y no me funciona, quien podría ayudarme a realizarla por favor!!!

Comment: var usersAdmin = Users.Where( u => u.Role == "Admin"); // algo asi

Comment: Cuando hago ese where no me deja traer Role me muestra es UserRoles y con ese no me deja comparar

Comment: Por favor, no uses imágenes salvo que sea absolutamente necesario. Mira por favor [aca](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/3976/324). Los errores y tu codigo deben ir como texto formateado segun corresponda (si es un error como comentario, si es codigo como codigo),siempre. y que se supone que tiene Users? capaz tiene una lista de roles y por eso ves eso, deberiamos ver como esta definido... EN TEXTo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Prueba con esto:

```
var lista = (from u in _userManager.Users
             where u.UserRoles.Count() == 1 &&
             u.UserRoles.FirstOrDefault().Role.NombreRol == "Admin"
             select u).ToList();
```

En esta consulta utilizamos el **operador Count** para obtener la cantidad de roles por cada usuario, seleccionando de esta forma los usuarios que solo tienen un rol y que este sea además **"Admin"**.

En este ejemplo asumo que tu **entidad Role** tiene la **propiedad NombreRol** de tipo **string** la cual almacena el nombre del rol, en tu modelo esa propiedad quizá tenga otro nombre, revisa bien y adapta este código a tus necesidades.

Comment: Me da este error "El operador '==' no se puede aplicar a operandos del tipo 'ApplicationRole' y 'string' ". Ese es el error que siempre me sale cuando comparo

Comment: @SebastianAgudelo eso es pq tienes que acceder a la propiedad del objeto Role, revisa lo nuevo que puse

Comment: Gracias, si funciono.

Comment: @SebastianAgudelo si la respuesta te sirvió te agradecería que la marcaras como aceptada y dieras tu voto positivo, gracias